# Get values from submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a very simple form:

```
<form id="toBeTranslatedForm" action="actionpage.php" method="POST" >
        <textarea name="userInput" id="toBeTranslatedTextArea"></textarea>
        <select id="translationOptions">//dynamically filled</select>
        <input type="submit" value="Translate" />
</form>
```

Using Jquery I am detecting whether the form has been submitted:

```
function outputTranslated()
{
    $('#toBeTranslatedForm').submit(function() {
        //do stuff
    });
}
```

How do I get the text typed in the text area and the option selected in the select box from the form above? Ideally I would like to put them into an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can get value:

```
function outputTranslated() {
    $('#toBeTranslatedForm').submit(function() {
       var textareaval = $('#userInput').val();
       alert(textareaval);
    });
}
```

You can do the same for selection box by adding this line after the `textareaval` variable definition in the code above:

```
var selectval = $('#translationOptions').val();
```

Then, you can either use serialise, or you can put it into an array manually:

```
var a = [textareaval,selectval];
```

Comment: This doesn't put them into an array as requested.

Comment: Edited in 2017 but the example still uses jquery?

Answer (score 15):

Javascript only, using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(form);
  for (const [name,value] of data) {
    console.log(name, ":", value)
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
     <select name="sselectt">
       <option value="default" defaultSelected="true">-- Select --</option>
       <option value="foo">foo</option>
       <option value="bar">bar</option>
     </select>
     <label for="inpt">remember</label>
     <input id="inpt" name="rrememberr" type="checkbox" />
     <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get the data form the submit event

```js
function outputTranslated() {
    $('#toBeTranslatedForm').submit(function(evt) {
       const form = evt.target;
       // get the field that you want
       const userInputField = form.elements['userInput'];
       alert(userInputField.value);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is the clearest answer. A slight improvement: `const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form)); alert(data.userInput)`.

Comment: This is so much better than every other answer.  (At least for my use-case, which is React.) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
var theArray = $('#toBeTranslatedForm').serializeArray();
```

See the [`.serializeArray` docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

On a pedantic note, that's not "from a submitted form", since you're asking for them before anything is actually submitted.

Comment: But how do I call on that array because I cant see where it sets the actual array

Comment: @RyanMurphy Edited... I assumed you'd read the link and saw that it returned an array.

Comment: this just outputs `[object, object]`

Comment: It's an array of objects, each of those objects are a name value pair.

Comment: @RyanMurphy Not really, it's the form values, in an array, as name value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'r looking for something like this.

```
$('#toBeTranslatedForm').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That serializes the form as a [URL-encoded string](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), not an array of values.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants a react version:

```
<form
  onSubmit={e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const elements = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
    const email = elements.get("email")
    console.log(email)
  }}
>
  Whatever
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

after submission, you can use just get the value by doing the following:

```
function outputTranslated()
{
$('#toBeTranslatedForm').submit(function() {
    var textarea = $('#toBeTranslatedTextArea').val();
    var allVals = [];
    $('#translationOptions :checked').each(function() {
   allVals.push($(this).val());
 });
});}
```