# select2 multi-value only sending one value in POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Here is a snippet of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/natatkinson/xbWEb/

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tags").select2({
        maximumSelectionSize: 3
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="GET">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Shoe Info</legend>
    <dl>    <dt>Name:</dt>

        <dd>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" placeholder="Shoe name" required autofocus>
        </dd>
    </dl>   <dt>Tags:</dt>

    <dd>
        <select multiple="" name="tags" id="tags" style="width:100%;">
            <option value="0">Select Tags</option>
            <option value="2">racing flat</option>
            <option value="3">track spikes</option>
            <option value="1">trainer</option>
        </select>
    </dd>
    </dl>
</fieldset>
<p class="submit-buttons">
    <input type="submit" class="button1" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Shoes" />
</p>
```

All that submits is 1 value, not a comma separated list like the documentation says.

Comment: have u tried using "tags[]" as name?

Comment: If I make a request with 3 tags listed, I see the following as the request URL: `/?name=abc&tags=0&tags=2&tags=3&submit=Add+Shoes`

Comment: @Tschitsch That's it! I'll notify the author to update their documentation. Can't believe I didn't try that sooner. Thanks

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You must use [] for multiple value contained form control's name.
Correct using at bottom:

```
<select multiple="" name="tags[]" id="tags" style="width:100%;">
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want the comma separated string of selected option?

Comment: @ankitsuthar Look the new answer, hope this can help you.

Comment: Yeah working for me smoothly as possible

Answer (score 3):

I think you can not get string data from select2 directly, you should add a hidden input, and submit the hidden input's value as param.

```
<input type="hidden" name="tags" id="tags"></input>
<select multiple="" style="width:100%;" onchange="changeSelect(event)">
  <option value="0">Select Tags</option>
  <option value="1">trainer</option>
</select>
function changeSelect(event){
  var select2Value = $(event.target).val();
  $("tags").val(select2Value);
}
```

Comment: This was not working for me so, I did this http://jsfiddle.net/gadalaavinash/Lxoq5jae/34/ based on the Jadzia here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955745/get-values-from-submitted-form